# Screens in SwitchNavigator Flicker on navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my react native app, I have a switch navigator to navigate between an Auth Stack and App Stack:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Auth",
  }
);
```

It works, however when I go from the AuthStack to the AppStack, it flickers and the screen moves up. How do I prevent this behaviour add have a smooth transition.

Comment: Does this occur only on the switch or also on the stack?

Comment: It only happens for the switch navigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the an animatedswitchnavigator instead of a normal switchnavigator and adding a transition:

```
import createAnimatedSwitchNavigator from 'react-navigation-animated-switch';
import { Transition } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const AppNavigator = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator(
  {
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Auth",
    transition: (
      <Transition.Together>
        <Transition.Out
          type="slide-bottom"
          durationMs={400}
          interpolation="easeIn"
        />
        <Transition.In type="fade" durationMs={500} />
      </Transition.Together>
    ),
  }
);
```

Documentation found here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/animated-switch-navigator/

Comment: For reference, the current version (5) of react-navigation as a very clean and powerful way to manage such transition: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animations